# scroll view is not responding when navigated again

Tags: iphone, ios

i had created a navigation based small application. When I click to the table row, it display controller having `UIScrollView` and number of `TextFields` added in it, when i returned back to main controller, then again i navigate to that controller, it do not scroll and still contain previous values in `textfield`. I am not able to know where is the problem.

Here is my code:

**rootcontroller.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   switch(indexPath.row)
    {       
        case 1: 
            if(insertViewController == nil)
        insertViewController = [[insertView alloc] initWithNibName:@"insertView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:insertViewController animated:YES];
            break;
            //[insertViewController release];
          }
  }
```

**insertviewcontoller.m**

```
#import "insertView.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

#define kTabBarHeight 5.0
#define kKeyboardAnimationDuration 1.0

@implementation insertView
@synthesize scroll;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        //for scrolling

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:self.view.window];
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                               object:self.view.window];
      keyboardIsShown = NO;
    //make contentSize bigger than your scrollSize (you will need to figure out for your own use case)
    CGSize scrollContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 345);
    self.scroll.contentSize = scrollContentSize;

}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil]; 
    // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                                  object:nil];  
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)n
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [n userInfo];

    // get the size of the keyboard
    NSValue* boundsValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [boundsValue CGRectValue].size;


    // resize the scrollview
    CGRect viewFrame = self.scroll.frame;
    // I'm also subtracting a constant kTabBarHeight because my UIScrollView was offset by the UITabBar so really only the portion of the keyboard that is leftover pass the UITabBar is obscuring my UIScrollView.
    viewFrame.size.height += (keyboardSize.height - kTabBarHeight);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    // The kKeyboardAnimationDuration I am using is 0.3
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kKeyboardAnimationDuration];
    [self.scroll setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    keyboardIsShown = NO;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)n
{
    // This is an ivar I'm using to ensure that we do not do the frame size adjustment on the UIScrollView if the keyboard is already shown.  This can happen if the user, after fixing editing a UITextField, scrolls the resized UIScrollView to another UITextField and attempts to edit the next UITextField.  If we were to resize the UIScrollView again, it would be disastrous.  NOTE: The keyboard notification will fire even when the keyboard is already shown.
    if (keyboardIsShown) {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [n userInfo];

    // get the size of the keyboard
    NSValue* boundsValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [boundsValue CGRectValue].size;

    // resize the noteView
    CGRect viewFrame = self.scroll.frame;
    // I'm also subtracting a constant kTabBarHeight because my UIScrollView was offset by the UITabBar so really only the portion of the keyboard that is leftover pass the UITabBar is obscuring my UIScrollView.
    viewFrame.size.height -= (keyboardSize.height - kTabBarHeight);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    // The kKeyboardAnimationDuration I am using is 0.3
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kKeyboardAnimationDuration];
    [self.scroll setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    keyboardIsShown = YES;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [scroll release];
    [nmtf release];
    [phtf release];
    [addtf release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update  `viewDidLoad` method  into `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` in your `insertviewcontoller.m` page

Comment: still having the same problem!! Again when i navigate to the insertview it shows privious value!and srolling get disabled